# jQuery Ajax using PHP function returns HTML code

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, joomla

I'm using Joomla, and I intend to be checked in a database of Joomla user table is right there through a code in order to perform the registration.

Well, 3 days ago I'm trying to use an ajax function that invokes a php function.
What happens is that when I try to read the response from the server (php function) can only get HTML page. Not sure what is happening. I saw several articles and questions and still not know what's going on.

What I'm doing is when the writing is detected in a given field, performs the function to check if the code exists in the database

I am unsure if I am correctly access to my validatePartner.php

Here is my script:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
jQuery(document).ready(
    function($){
        $('#jform_username').bind('input', function() {
            alert("FINE");

            var data =" hello world";
            var data2=" hello all";
            $.ajax({
                url: 'validatePartner.php',
                data: {'q': data,'z':data2},
                type: "POST",
                success: function(data) {
                    alert("Here: " + data);
                }

            });
        });
    });
</script>
```

Here is my validatePartner.php:

```
<?php
 function myfunction() {
    $myvar = $_POST['q']." how are you?";
    $myvar2 = $_POST['z'];
    echo $myvar."\n".$myvar2;

 }

myfunction();
?>
```

I have this teo files in the same directory.

Thanks for your help!

SOLUTION:

Using @jonasfh tips, I got what I need!
I created a component with two files that he tells me and in ajax function I used:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
. . .
$.ajax({
    url: '?option=com_validatepartner&format=raw',
    . . .
</script>
```

Instead:

```js
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
. . .
$.ajax({
    url: '?option=com_validatepartner&tmpl=json',
    . . .
</script>
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: What is the output you get?

Comment: I get HTML code page:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr"
   class='com_blankcomponent view-default itemid-120 home j32'>

<head>
   <base href=…...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you should probably make a component to return your ajax call as outlined by @MrCode. The component can be super simple, but needs at least 2 files(possibly some more?): an xml definition file, and the entry point, like this:

/administrator/components/com_validatepartner/validatepartner.xml and
/components/com_validatepartner/validatepartner.php

Syntax and format of the xml-file is described [here](http://docs.joomla.org/J3.2%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component#helloworld.xml). The file validatepartner.php can be as simple as:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
#get a database object
$db=JFactory::getDbo(); 
$db->setQuery('select * from #__thetable'); 
$list=$db->loadAssocList(); 
# you probably want to return some json-data or something: 
echo json_encode($list);
```

Now one more trick: In your template folder add the following file: 
json.php

containing:

```
defined('_JEXEC') or die;
<jdoc:include type="component" />
```

Now you can test your component by going to:

index.php?option=com_validatepartner #result inside the normal tmpl-file

and

index.php?option=com_validatepartner&tmpl=json # to use your json.php tmpl-file

Finally call the file similar to what @MrCode suggested, with small changes

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_validatepartner&tmpl=json',
    data: {'q': data,'z':data2},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Here: " + data);
    }

});
```

Also remember to register the component in the joomla backend, by going to extensions->extension-manager and then Discovery.

regards Jonas

Edit: Changed layout to tmpl in the above code and examples. Also changed some of the file layout etc.

Comment: Thanks for your detailed response. I will try what you and @MrCode sugested and later I come to say if it worked.

Comment: Sorry for this question… In xml file, since I do not use all files sugested in "Developing a MVC Component/Developing a Basic Component", I'm little confused what I need to put in:<files folder="site">
                <filename>index.html</filename>
                <filename>helloworld.php</filename>
        </files>

Comment: I think youll only need to put the one php-file in the site-section. You can try it. When installing using the discovery-function, I dont think the xml-file is that important, as the files are already in the right location.

Comment: OK! I got my result, but seems it is encapsulated in HTML. In ajax function I used **url: index.php?option=com_validatepartner** (**index.php?option=com_validatepartner&tmpl=json** doesn't return anything). I apologize for the number of responses.

Comment: hmm, not sure why nothing displays when you use tmpl=json. Try tmpl=component. This should use the component.php-file in /templates/system (or be overridden in your template, if you have a component.php - file there). component.php displays the component wrapped in a minimum of html.

Comment: I was bad indicate the path, now everything works as it should. The only problem is that the result appears in **alert("Here: " + data);**, but embedded in the html code of the page. I just wanted to print a column of the result, eg the ID (data.id). I do not know how to do. I tried to use **alert("Here: " + data.id);** but is displayed "undefined". Thanks for all the help.

Comment: Glad it's working. I'm not really sure how your returned json-data looks now, but you need to parse the json-data. Try alert("Here: "+JSON.parse(data).id); or alert("Here: "+JSON.parse(data)['id']); JSON.parse should parse your JSON-data into javascript object / array.

Comment: I don't know why, but seems that exists a problem using JSON in ajax function. I've tried before add **datatype: 'json'** to ajax function. Tried anyway your sugestion, but it seems that the code doesn´t recognize JSON command: **SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character**.

Comment: Ok, now I'm trying in my validatepartner.php return a string: **echo 'test response';**. What I receive is the same thing: '<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-gb" dir="ltr"
   class='com_validatepartner view-form layout-edit itemid-305 j32'>

<head> . . . . ', among this html I get my string.

Answer (score 0):

Your request to validatePartner.php is probably being rewritten to the Joomla! index.php. In any case, you should create a native Joomla! component that can be called via the Joomla! index.php, instead of creating a separate script file. Your separate PHP script won't have access to the Joomla! database or session etc.

It would then be called like:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'index.php?option=com_myComponent&task=validatePartner',
    data: {'q': data,'z':data2},
    type: "POST",
    success: function(data) {
        alert("Here: " + data);
    }

});
```

- [Developing a Basic Joomla! Component](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aDeveloping_a_MVC_Component/Developing_a_Basic_Component)

Comment: Hi! Thanks for your reply. My validatePartner.php is inside template files (where is index.php and another files) and can access to database, since I test it previously. I'm using script inside registration file (base file of Joomla) where form is created, but perhaps there is some failure in the data exchange.

Comment: Hi again. So what you suggested was create a component where I put my php function, and my script remains in the form file as is currently? And this php file can access to the database? Thanks!

Comment: Yes, your component will have full access to the framework, and you can call it via ajax anywhere on any of your views or templates.

Comment: Is it really so hard to make one simple ajax request wich returns `1` in joomla ?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. I was working on dependent drop down lists using jQuery in joomla component. The second drop down list as result of call display empty and loads with html page. At last I found the solution: the requisite file should be placed outside the components directory. As a result, we won't be able to get the entire html page, but at that page we have to include libraries externally.

Here are the libraries:

```
define( '_JEXEC', 1 );    
define('JPATH_BASE', dirname(__FILE__));   
define( 'DS', DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR );   
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'defines.php' );   
require_once ( JPATH_BASE .DS.'includes'.DS.'framework.php' );  
$mainframe =& JFactory::getApplication('site');  
$mainframe->initialise();
```