# Run custom php code in joomla module backend page

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, joomla-extensions

i am using Joomla 2.5 , 
I am working on a module .My module loads some javascripts in frontend. I want to run few php code in backend, when admin click on save button. How to do that?

Comment: You could follow what is outlined in this question: 

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968685/jquery-ajax-using-php-function-returns-html-code/22975859#22975859][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22968685/jquery-ajax-using-php-function-returns-html-code/22975859#22975859

Comment: Sorry, thought you wanted to execute on the server, now I see it's on the server in the backend/admin- area on module save. There is this post on the joomla-forum, but I'm not sure if it works... http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?f=578&t=554174

Comment: Thank you for reply , I am thinking if i try to do form validation on custom field(backend) at save button ,i can add my custom php code in between , I need to search how to do form validation for custom field in module.

Comment: Custom code includes sending post request to url , i am looking for php way , not ajax . For example in drupal cms , there are direct functions/hooks(drupalchat_settings_form_validate) which called automatically when admin press save button.

Answer (score 0):

You can write a plugin that uses the event trigger onBeforeSave, then when you hit the save button, the plugin is run.
You can do any validation on the data sent by post, if it fails just return false and you will return to your form.

You can see some documentation on how to do this here:

http://docs.joomla.org/Plugin/Events

[http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5:Creating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla](http://docs.joomla.org/J2.5%3aCreating_a_Plugin_for_Joomla)

Comment: Thanks for reply . I have solved the problem 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23359075/save-form-field-in-component-params-joomla/23367596?noredirect=1#23367596