# Server side validation in module setting page in backend joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5

I am using joomla 2.5, i am working on joomla module, i want to perform server side custom form validation at backend setting page in module. I have checked joomla forums , but they all explained according to component , i strictly need to do it in module . I am new in joomla . Please explain the method.

Comment: what kind of validation you required ?

Comment: lets say , match some pattern.

Comment: check the answer its the right way without hack core! Otherwise you have to try with jQuery onblur event to validate the pattern

Comment: Actually i wanted achieve different task , can u checkout http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23266011/run-custom-php-code-in-joomla-module-backend-page

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

First of all you can't do a wide variety of validations like components forms in module params without hacking the core.

the available options are limiting INT,RAW data string only.

you can use the last option of module params called `filter`. [Details](http://docs.joomla.org/Form_field)  take a look at [this](http://docs.joomla.org/Text_form_field_type).

```
<field name="myintvalue" type="text" default="8" label="Enter some text" description="Enter some description" filter="integer" />

<field name="myhtmlvalue" type="text" default="" label="Enter some text" description="Enter some description" filter="raw" />
```

Alternate Options.

You can create a custom rule for validation. For example your module name is `mod_mymodule`:

- Add `addrulepath` attribute to the fieldset in the .xml file:

  ```
  addrulepath="modules/mod_mymodule"
  ```

This will be the path to the custom rule folder.

- Add `validate` attribute to the field with the name of the rule file:

  ```
  validate="testint"
  ```

This will give us the file `testint.php`.

- Create the rule file `testint.php` and put it to the path specified in the `addrulepath` attribute. So the full path will be:

  `administrator/modules/mod_mymodule/testint.php`

Here is a simple validation rule class:

```
class JFormRuleTestint extends JFormRule
{
    public function test(&$element, $value, $group = null, &$input = null, &$form = null)
    {
        return ((int)$value > 0 && (int)$value < 2);
    }
}
```

it should extend `JFormRule` class and you will need only one method, called `test`. `$value` will contain the input from the field. Here we are testing it to be integer between 0 and 2.

Hope its helps..